# Cannot depoly cloud functions containing stripe

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Even if i simply write a helloWorld function and import stripe in it, the cloud function won't deploy but as soon as i remove the stripe line, it does. I have stripe installed using npm. I have linting enabled to show if there's any error while importing - there isn't. I checked the firebase console to see if errors are logged but there's only one error with code 3. Meaning that the code that i wrote is wrong. But the fact is that it is simply a helloworld function that is commented out at the beginning of getting started with cloud functions. I've tried switching languages from javascript to typescript and tried different ways of importing but to no avail. Someone else facing the same problem? BTW when I upload the function, for some reason it always uploads to usCentral1 but my default location is asiaSouth, could that be any issue as to why my function is not deploying with stripe integrated?

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_...U7S", {
    apiVersion: '2020-08-27'
})

admin.initializeApp();

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, 
   response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  console.log(stripe.balance);
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is 
likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"j...1@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/testeastylian/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld"}
```

my -- package.json -- file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "stripe": "^8.163.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0"
  }
}
```

This is the package.json file inside functions folder

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code and a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @Dharmaraj added the initial code and the error produced in firebase logs

Comment: Have you enabled the logs as reported in the firebase error? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? I'd like to confirm the SDK versions you are using.

Comment: @Dharmaraj we're using the same dependencies .. thanks anyway.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato haven't tried their logging library but i did log using console log

Comment: Can you please try creating a new directory and try once? If it still doesn't work share a screenshot from your terminal from where you are deploying (complete log).

Comment: You need to actually call a method on `stripe.balance`. For example, `stripe.balance.retrieve()`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_retrieve?lang=node

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating initializing Firebase project locally both in Javascript and Typescript and the SDK seems to be working in both. Have you initialized the project correctly.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_...U7S", {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});

admin.initializeApp();

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  console.log(stripe.balance);
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

This function works perfectly. I'd recommend trying to initialize Firebase project in a new directory and clean install all node modules. I ran the exact same commands below:

```bash
# create new directory
firebase init functions
# select Typescript and enable ESLint
cd functions
npm i stripe
npm i -D @types/stripe
# paste the code above in index.ts
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Also make sure you are using latest version of Firebase CLI and Firebase Functions. I had these version while testing:

```
"@types/stripe": "^8.0.417",
"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
"stripe": "^8.163.0"
```